# Test Application on iPhone 3G without SIM card

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, push-notification

I am working on one application that has APNS in the same. And for the same purpose,i have installed an SSL certificate in the application. For the purpose of getting the device token,i am attaching the device with MAC and the organizer window starts connecting to the iPhone device and starts copying the files but it sticks at a point saying copying file 2 of 2 and takes hours but in vain.The symbol next to device remains orange in Organizer. I am using Xcode version 3.2.6 and have iPhone 3G for testing.

Is this possible due to No SIM in the iPhone device or some other reason? Kindly help. I really have lost so much time on the same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which iOS version is there in iPhone 3G?

Comment: The symbol next to device should show green in Organizer. If not try connecting to mac it will show pop to collect information accept it then try.

Comment: @ iPhoneiPadDev  : iphone 3G is having version 4.2.1

Comment: @iamsult : That it shows,then after clicking the collect button it starts copying the files but the process never finishes. It just shows msg like copying file 2 of 2 for hours and hours

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but it sounds like there is something wrong with the device. I think you should try to reset it to the factory defaults (using iTunes) and start again. There is no problem with the missing SIM card, you do not need a SIM card for any purpose except making phone calls and accessing 3G data services. Everything else will function perfectly without a SIM card.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert : thanks for the reply. I was told that the iPhone was upgraded recently so can there be anything wrong in iPhone only? I mean is it possible that Mac OS 10.7.2 is clashes with iPhone os?

Comment: No, Mac OS X 10.7.2 will be perfectly fine with it. It only takes a few minutes restore the phone's firmware with iTunes (depending how fast your internet is), so you should try that.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert : okay.Thank you. Let me try with the same. Anyways thank you for the quick replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it the same reason or not but after testing my application on iPhone 3GS, i was able to run my app successfully.